# HTML Anchors scrolling parent frame

Tags: javascript, html

I have an iframe with anchor links eg  `Click <a href="#chapter4">` however when the iframe scrolls to the anchor, the parent frame also scrolls to the top, is there anyway to stop this?

Comment: Can you supply a jsfiddle example of what you are talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to solve a similar problem and ended up using javascript. Give id to your anchors and use the scrollIntoView() method.

```
function onclick(event) {
window.frames['nameOfiFrame'].document.getElementById("anchorId").scrollIntoView();
return false;
}
```

link

```
<a id="anchorId">go</a>
```

EDIT: If it doesn't affect your design, I believe that you can use css position:fixed; to prevent it. You provide little information. :)